# TypeError in Nonce [Web3, Python, FlashBot]

Tags: web3js, web3.py, python, nonce

Here is the code.

When I wrote the private key of sender's address without string, it showed me provide sender's key as string.

When I wrote the private key of sender's address in string, it showed me error that it cannot be convert in bytes.

Can anyone please help me about this?

```py
from web3 import Web3, HTTPProvider

# Own Ethereum node URL (ETH Provider URL)
node_url = "https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/"

# Initialize Web3 instance
w3 = Web3(HTTPProvider(node_url))

# Private key of the sender's Ethereum address
sender_private_key = "xxxxxxxxxxxx"

# Receiver's Ethereum address
receiver_address = "0xxxxxxxxxxx"

# Replace this with the amount of Ether you want to send
amount_to_send = xxxxxx

# Convert the amount to Wei (1 Ether = 10^18 Wei)
amount_in_wei = w3.from_wei(amount_to_send, 'ether')

# Nonce for the sender's address
nonce = w3.eth.get_transaction_count(w3.eth.account.from_key(sender_private_key))

# Defining the transaction
transaction = {
    'to': receiver_address,
    'value': amount_in_wei,
    'gas': 21000,
    'nonce': nonce,
}

# Sign the transaction
signed_transaction = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(transaction, sender_private_key)

# Send the signed transaction
transaction_hash = w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_transaction)

# Print the transaction hash
print(f"Transaction hash: {transaction_hash.hex()}")
```

Answer (score 1):

Dev Advocate at [Chainstack](https://chainstack.com/) here!

You can use the following code to send a transaction to another account. I'm using `web3==6.5.0` here.

```py
from web3 import Web3, HTTPProvider
from eth_account import Account
from eth_account.signers.local import LocalAccount

# Configuration
node_url = "RPC_URL"  # Ethereum node URL
sender_private_key = "0x_private_key"  # Sender's Ethereum private key
receiver_address = ("receiver_address"  # Receiver's Ethereum address)
amount_to_send = 0.5  # Amount of Ether to send (in Ether, not Wei)

# Initialize Web3 instance
w3 = Web3(HTTPProvider(node_url))

# Ensure that the node is connected
if not w3.is_connected():
    raise Exception("Web3 is not connected to the Ethereum node")

# Validate private key format
if not sender_private_key.startswith("0x"):
    raise ValueError("Private key must start with 0x")

# Transaction preparation
amount_in_wei = w3.to_wei(amount_to_send, "ether")
account: LocalAccount = Account.from_key(sender_private_key)
sender_address = account.address
nonce = w3.eth.get_transaction_count(sender_address)
base_gas_price = w3.eth.gas_price
priority_fee = w3.to_wei(1, "gwei")
gas_price_with_priority = base_gas_price + priority_fee
estimated_gas = w3.eth.estimate_gas(
    {"from": sender_address, "to": receiver_address, "value": amount_in_wei}
)
chain_id = w3.eth.chain_id

# Defining the transaction
transaction = {
    "to": receiver_address,
    "value": amount_in_wei,
    "gas": estimated_gas,
    "gasPrice": gas_price_with_priority,
    "nonce": nonce,
    "chainId": chain_id,
}

print(f"Sending {amount_to_send} to {receiver_address}")
print(f"Current network chain ID: {chain_id}")
print(f"Base network gas price: {base_gas_price} Wei")
print(f"Gas price with priority fee: {gas_price_with_priority} Wei")
print(f"Transaction details:", transaction)

# Transaction signing and sending
print("Signing the transaction...")
signed_transaction = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(transaction, sender_private_key)
print("Sending the transaction...")
transaction_hash = w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_transaction.rawTransaction)

# Transaction hash output
print(f"Transaction sent! Hash: {transaction_hash.hex()}")
```

Running this code will make a transfer and output something like this:

```sh
Sending 0.5 to RECEIVER
Current network chain ID: 11155111
Base network gas price: 83421486 Wei
Gas price with priority fee: 1083421486 Wei
Transaction details: {'to': 'RECEIVER', 'value': 1000000000000000, 'gas': 21000, 'gasPrice': 1083421486, 'nonce': 98, 'chainId': 11155111}
Signing the transaction...
Sending the transaction...
Transaction sent! Hash: HASH
```

> Make sure your private key starts with `0x`.

Here is a breakdown of the code:

1. **Configuration**: Sets up essential details like the Ethereum node URL, your private key, the receiver's address, and the amount of Ether to send.
2. **Web3 Initialization**: Connects to the Ethereum blockchain using the provided node URL.
3. **Validation and Preparation**: Validates the private key format, converts the Ether amount to Wei (the smallest Ethereum unit), calculates the gas price with an additional priority fee, and estimates the necessary gas for the transaction. It also retrieves the sender's address and transaction count (nonce).
4. **Building the Transaction**: Constructs a transaction object with all necessary details, including the `chainId`.
5. **Signing and Sending**: Signs the transaction with the sender's private key for authentication and sends it to the Ethereum network.
6. **Output**: Prints transaction details and the transaction hash after sending.

Noticed how I added the `chainId` to the transaction, the transaction will not work without it:

- **Replay Attack Prevention**: `chainId` distinguishes transactions for a specific Ethereum network, preventing replay attacks where a transaction from one network could be fraudulently repeated on another.
- **Network Compliance**: Post-EIP-155, the `chainId` is required for a transaction to be recognized as valid and accepted by the Ethereum network.

You can find more examples using web3.py on the [Chainstack docs](https://docs.chainstack.com/reference/ethereum-sendrawtransaction). Also, feel free to reach out if you have more questions!